# Can someone explain the behavior of the functions mkpp and ppval?

Tags: function, matlab, arguments, octave, polynomial-math

If I do the following in MATLAB:

```
ppval(mkpp(1:2, [1 0 0 0]),1.5)
ans =  0.12500
```

This should construct a polynomial `f(x) = x^3` and evaluate it at `x = 1.5`. So why does it give me the result `1.5^3 = .125`? Now, if I change the domain defined in the first argument to `mkpp`, I get this:

```
> ppval(mkpp([1 1.5 2], [[1 0 0 0]; [1 0 0 0]]), 1.5)
ans = 0
```

So without changing the function, I change the answer. Awesome.

Can anyone explain what's going on here? How does changing the first argument to `mkpp` change the result I get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [MKPP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mkpp.html) will *shift* the polynomial so that `x = 0` will start at the beginning of the corresponding range you give it. In your first example, the polynomial `x^3` is shifted to the range `[1 2]`, so if you want to evaluate the polynomial at an *unshifted* range of `[0 1]`, you would have to do the following:

```
>> pp = mkpp(1:2,[1 0 0 0]);   %# Your polynomial
>> ppval(pp,1.5+pp.breaks(1))  %# Shift evaluation point by the range start

ans =

    3.3750                     %# The answer you expect
```

In your second example, you have one polynomial `x^3` shifted to the range `[1 1.5]` and another polynomial `x^3` shifted to the range of `[1.5 2]`. Evaluating the piecewise polynomial at `x = 1.5` gives you a value of zero, occurring at the start of the second polynomial.

It may help to visualize the polynomials you are making as follows:

```
x = linspace(0,3,100);                     %# A vector of x values
pp1 = mkpp([1 2],[1 0 0 0]);               %# Your first piecewise polynomial
pp2 = mkpp([1 1.5 2],[1 0 0 0; 1 0 0 0]);  %# Your second piecewise polynomial
subplot(1,2,1);                            %# Make a subplot
plot(x,ppval(pp1,x));                      %# Evaluate and plot pp1 at all x
title('First Example');                    %# Add a title
subplot(1,2,2);                            %# Make another subplot
plot(x,ppval(pp2,x));                      %# Evaluate and plot pp2 at all x
axis([0 3 -1 8])                           %# Adjust the axes ranges
title('Second Example');                   %# Add a title
```

[image]

Comment: I've been staring at this for so long... Thank you! If I want to evaluate it at some vector of points how would I do it? Is there a better function to use than ppval?

Comment: @Xodarap: You can pass a vector of points to [PPVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ppval.html) as illustrated in my sample plotting code above.