# Converting matlabs mkpp to python

Tags: python, matlab, math

I am trying to convert some matlab code into python and ran into the mkpp function of matlab.  I have read many different things on interpolation in python using scipy, but I cant understand how to mimic the functionality of the matlab code.  I tried using the interpolate.PiecewisePolynomial in scipy, but it doesnt seem to take the same arguments, which in matlab are breaks and coefficients.  Is there a source of what matlab is actually doing?  How can the functions of mkpp be mimicked in python?

EDIT:
So from the comment below, yes I have tried looking at the mkpp file,

```
if nargin==2, d = 1; else d = d(:).'; end
dlk=numel(coefs); l=length(breaks)-1; dl=prod(d)*l; k=fix(dlk/dl+100*eps);
if (k<=0)||(dl*k~=dlk)
   error(message('MATLAB:mkpp:PPNumberMismatchCoeffs',...
       int2str(l),int2str(d),int2str(dlk)))
end

pp.form = 'pp';
pp.breaks = reshape(breaks,1,l+1);
pp.coefs = reshape(coefs,dl,k);
pp.pieces = l;
pp.order = k;
pp.dim = d;
```

Is what the file says, and I cant find any file for pp, so it seems useless.

Ive read through this: [Can someone explain the behavior of the functions mkpp and ppval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196417/can-someone-explain-the-behavior-of-the-functions-mkpp-and-ppval)   However, it still doesnt explain what matlab is doing behind the scenes, its just explaining that it is different then a regular polynomial.

The problem I have with even starting to figure it out is that everything I find for scipy takes different arguments than mkpp.  I have written python code to create the coefs and breaks, but the scipy documentation http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PiecewisePolynomial.html#scipy.interpolate.PiecewisePolynomial doesnt even reference the variables in the same way, making it extremely confusing.

It would be nice if someone could help parse this out as to what the terminology being used means

Comment: You may be interested in the `mkpp.m` file in your matlab directory, or `edit mkpp` in the matlab command window.

Comment: edit mkpp doesnt show much:

if nargin==2, d = 1; else d = d(:).'; end
dlk=numel(coefs); l=length(breaks)-1; dl=prod(d)*l; k=fix(dlk/dl+100*eps);
if (k<=0)||(dl*k~=dlk)
   error(message('MATLAB:mkpp:PPNumberMismatchCoeffs',...
       int2str(l),int2str(d),int2str(dlk)))
end

pp.form = 'pp';
pp.breaks = reshape(breaks,1,l+1);
pp.coefs = reshape(coefs,dl,k);
pp.pieces = l;
pp.order = k;
pp.dim = d;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, here is what my confusion was and this is how i understand it now.  pp is not actually a function, but a call to a struct which defined a polynomial.  mkpp is simply creating the components of the polynomial which can then be used with ppval or spline or any other analysis method.  In order to mimic this, i created the following code, which is a work in progress but should give a good idea as to how it would work:

First I use a class to define the polynomial

```
class PiecePoly():
    """
    A class to mimick the MATLAB struct piecewise polynomial (pp)
    """
    def __init__(self):
        form = 'pp'
        breaks = []
        coefs = []
        pieces = 0
        order = 0
        dim = 0
```

Then the function mkpp is:

```
def mkpp(breaks,coefs,*args):
    """
    Takes in the breaks, coefs, and optionally (d) then creates a pp from the 
    PiecePoly class and constructs the polynomial
    Returns: the constructed polynomial
    """
    if len(args)==1:
        d = np.transpose(args[0])
    else:
        d = 1
    sum=0
    try:
        #Just make sure coefs is not a 4D matrix
        for i in range(len(coefs)):
            for j in range(len(coefs[i])):
                sum = sum+len(coefs[i][j])
    except:
        #First try to count a 2D coefs array this should be the one that works
        try:
            for i in range(len(coefs)):
                sum = sum+len(coefs[i])
        #Coefs must be 1 dimensional
        except:
            sum = len(coefs)

    dlk = sum
    l = len(breaks)-1

    try:
        if len(d) > 1:
            prod = 0
            for i in range(len(d)):
                prod = prod*d[i]
            dl = prod*l
        else:
            dl = d*l
    except:
        dl = d*l

    k = dlk/dl+100*(math.pow(2,-52))
    if k<0:
        k = math.ceil(k)
    else:
        k = math.floor(k)

    if k<=0 or (dl*k!=dlk):
        print "ERROR: MISMATCH PP AND COEF"
        return None

    pp = PiecePoly()
    pp.form = 'pp'
    pp.breaks = np.reshape(breaks,1,l+1)
    pp.coefs = np.reshape(coefs,dl,k)
    pp.order = k
    pp.dim = d

    return pp
```